# Prove composition of bijections is bijection

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

Let f : A → B and g : B → C be bijections. Prove that g◦f : A → C is a bijection

Can someone show me the steps I should take to solve this problem?

Comment: Do you understand what a bijection is?

Comment: See the definitions of bijection and function composition.

Comment: Shouldn't it be "Prove that $f \circ g$ is a bijection?

Comment: Composition is right to left.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since they are bijections they have inverses $f^{-1},g^{-1}$. from $B$ to $A$ and from $C$ to $B$

$(g\circ f)\circ(f^{-1}\circ g^{-1})=(g\circ 1_C)\circ g^{-1}=1_C$

$(f^{-1}\circ g^{-1})\circ(g\circ f)=(f^{-1}\circ1_A)\circ f=1_A$

so $g\circ f$ has an inverse and thus is bijective.

Answer (score -1):

$f$ takes elements from $A$ to $B$ and $g$ takes elements from $B$ to $C$. It doesn't make sense to speak of the composition $g \circ f$ because $f(c)$ is not necessarily defined for all $c \in C$. I believe you are supposed to show $f \circ g = f(g(x))$ is one-to-one and onto. To show one-to-one, show that for all $x,y \in A$ where $x \neq y$  that $f(g(x)) \neq f(g(y))$. To show onto, let $c \in C$ and show that you can find $a \in A$ such that $f(g(a))=c$. You already know that $g,f$ are one-to-one and onto, and you can use that to piece together that $f(g(x))$ is one-to-one and onto.

Comment: There seems to be something wrong with this answer. "$f$ takes elements from $A$ to $B$ and $g$ takes elements from $B$ to $C$." If that is the case, then "$f(c)$ is not necessarily defined for all $c\in C$" does not make sense.